# How to change the text of my x axis ticks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to remove the numbers from my x-axis ticks and replace them with my two variable "male" and "female" when I plot them with ggplot2.

Here is what I have currently:

```
cces_bar <- cces %>%
  mutate(gender_gun = case_when(
    gender == 1 ~ "Male",
    gender == 2 ~ "Female",
    ))

cces_bar <- cces %>%
  mutate(gun_control = case_when(
    CC18_320a == 1 ~ "Support",
    CC18_320a == 2 ~ "Oppose",
    CC18_320a == 8 ~ "Skip"
  ))

cces_bar %>% ggplot(aes(x = gender, fill = gun_control))+
  geom_bar(color = "black", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Gender") +
  ylab("Observations") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("Oppose" = "red", "Support" = "green")) +
  theme_light()+ggtitle("Support / Oppose Background Checks On Gun Sales by Gender")
```

Comment: The issue you have is that you you never transformed `gender`. Look at your first code. You have `gun_control` insted of gender

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be almost OK, just you probably wanted to use `gender_gun` rather than `gender` for x axis inside `ggplot()` and you forgot to mutate at the new data frame:

```
cces_bar <- cces %>%
  mutate(gender_gun = case_when(
    gender == 1 ~ "Male",
    gender == 2 ~ "Female",
    ))

# here you want to keep the previous change and add another column
# i.e. use 'cces_bar' rather than 'cces'
cces_bar <- cces_bar %>%
  mutate(gun_control = case_when(
    CC18_320a == 1 ~ "Support",
    CC18_320a == 2 ~ "Oppose",
    CC18_320a == 8 ~ "Skip"
  ))

# use 'gender_gun' instead of 'gender'
cces_bar %>% ggplot(aes(x = gender_gun, fill = gun_control))+
  geom_bar(color = "black", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Gender") +
  ylab("Observations") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("Oppose" = "red", "Support" = "green")) +
  theme_light()+ggtitle("Support / Oppose Background Checks On Gun Sales by Gender")
```